# Принудительно очистить браузер от кэша принудительно сайтом по условию

Tags: javascript, браузер, кэширование

Столкнулся с колоссальной проблемой. Не кидайте картошками, скажу сразу облазил все и всЁ, и ничего не подходит к моим нуждам. Уже руки вбились в кровь искать варианты и решения.

По этому пришел сюда.

По Сушеству:

1. Есть сайт, сайт периодически обновляют на новую версию, и после перехода на новую версию случаются проблема касательно кэша в браузере у клиента.
2. Есть принудительная очистка кэша на сайте, но как сообщает поддержка она нужна для: "Кеш в админке чистится для проекта. Но у каждого пользователя есть еще кеш браузера, его почистить из админки невозможно."

Решение в определенных случаях помогает на пользовательском ПК использовать комбинацию Ctrl+Shift+R или же через инспектор в браузере включить функцию "отключить кэш" и тогда выполняется загрузка.

Нашел вот такой код:

```
function verificarNovaVersio() {
var sVersio = localStorage['gcf_versio'+ location.pathname] || 'v00.0.0000';
$.ajax({
    url: './_upload/js/versio.txt',
    dataType: 'text',
    cache: 'false',
    contentType: 'false',
    processData: 'false',
    type: 'post'
 }).done(function(sVersioFitxer) {
    console.log('Versió App: '+ sVersioFitxer +', Versió Caché: '+ sVersio);
    if (sVersio < (sVersioFitxer || 'v00.0.0000')) {
        localStorage['gcf_versio'+ location.pathname] = sVersioFitxer;
        location.reload(true);
    }
});
}
```

в папке создал файл "**versio.txt**" и указал версию **v00.0.0001**
но почему то у меня это не сработало.

Мне бы подошел такой вариант:
Если скажем сайт обновился с версии 3.15 на версию 3.16, то в определённом файлике указываем версию сайта, и пользователь при посещения сайта, видит разницу в версии у себя с кэше и файле на сайте и выполняет перезагрузку сайта с полной очисткой кэша и куков этой страницы скажем аналог  Ctrl+Shift+R или аналог инспектора Отключить кэш.

Желательно все это реализовать через JS код, так как нет возможности вносить изменения в php, apache, htacces, а только внедрить код js.

Самой собой первым делов в Meta теги включил эти сроки:

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
```

Comment: Какое-то удаление гланд ректально. Есть же миллион статей про версионирование и настройку заголовков кэширования.

Comment: Самое простое, добавлять версию к урлам загрузки статики (если у вас проблема в этом)

Comment: @peter  да это есть https://ibb.co/wh67dt9 проблема именно в прогрузке модулей которые грузятся скажем типо во фрейе, но по факту подгружаются по api. По этому и создал статью, так как отключение или очистка браузерного кеша у пользователя помогает.